# Taxonomy Hierarchy URL

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy vocabulary with  name "Animals" along with following terms

- Mammals
  - Animalia
  - Chordata
  - Mammalia
    - Bat
    - Bear
    - Fox

I have created a view with contextual filters in which I need to show the hierarchy of the taxonomy terms
For example : URL : base_URL/Mammals/Mammalia/Bat

Taxonomy Implementation that I have made :

- Added relationship of taxonomy terms on node
- Added relationship of parent term
- Added contextual filters for parent term.
- Added contextual filters for taxonomy term id with depth.
  (Please find the settings of the same in attached screenshot).

But actual results I'm getting is "base_URL/tid" but expected URL result what I need is "base_URL/Mammals/Mammalia/Bat".

Can anyone please help me out with detailed implementation?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any screenshot.

It seems that your problem is with url and if it is then
go for [Path Auto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module.

The Pathauto module automatically generates URL/path aliases for various kinds of content (nodes, taxonomy terms, users) without requiring the user to manually specify the path alias.